Intuitive explanation of commutation relations of Special Conformal Transformations (SCTs) and momentum generators?
Some entries in the conformal algebra can be intuitively justified: the Lorentz algebra says stuff like rotation+rotation=rotation, boost+boost=rotation, etc. The momentum and angular momentum commutators simply say that the momentum transforms as a Lorentz vector. Same for Special Conformal Transformations (SCT). The dilatation-momentum and dilatation-SCT commutators just say that scaling dimensions $\Delta$ are increased and decreased respectively. The mysterious entry is  $$[K_\mu,P_\nu]=2(\eta_{\mu \nu}D-M_{\mu \nu}) \tag{1}$$
Can this be given some intuitive meaning as to what is going on under the hood? One possible partial answer might be: for $\mu,\nu=0,0$ for example, we get $[K_0,P_0]=-2 D$ which means the difference of translation of infinity and translation of origin and doing the same in reverse order amounts to just a rescaling! Is this an easy to imagine thing? Can something else be said or well known for this and the other components of commutators in $(1)$?
EDIT: Initially I was looking for more of a geometric understanding, but now I am open to having a symmetry/dimensional analysis/consistency based argument of why the commutator looks like $(1)$. For example, we allow $D$ and $M$ because they are the only dimensionally consistent ones (as pointed out in the comments by Cosmas Zachos). I can see that we must bring $\eta_{\mu \nu}$ with $D$ because there's no other choice (e.g. $M_{\mu \nu}$ would make it a non-Lie algebra: so will inclusion of higher powers of $D$ for example). Can we "guess" the factor of $2$ and the minus sign in between by any means?

Does WP help? Not sure about geometrical intuition, but algebraically it is all but inevitable...

Sorry. I already did the algebra. I was particularly looking for a geometrical intuition or maybe any "physical insight" at all. I became more curious for an intuitive understanding because, for example in this review, on pg. 4 Eberhardt discusses "the meaning" of all these commutators... except this one.

Well, your ref says that commutator is needed for algebraic closure, namely a gradient [dim 1] commuted with [dim -1] operators will yield [dim 0] operators: all of them.  The dilatation commutators are of exactly the same nature: algebraic instead of geometrical. You are chasing a mirage...

Hmm. Okay, can you give a heuristic algebraic justification of the factor of $2$ and the minus sign in between without doing the full math in detail? I will also edit the question accordingly if you want to post an answer.

Sorry, I did not understand that. There is only one momentum, right? And whose square are we talking about here: I mean which $x$? I am totally lost.

Hi @Nairit Sahoo: Link to reference/notes? Just to fix conventions.

No, no geometric intuition for the precise 2 and - in your (1) available, beyond closure of the entire algebra... I was just justifying the presence of D and M on the r.h.s. ...
